# OGR reports incorrect SRS for GeoJSON

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, ogr, epsg

OGR (GDAL 3.2.2) appears to incorrectly read the SRS of GeoJSON features and I would like to know if there is anything I can do to prevent this.

I have two GeoJSON files and both represent the same feature.

File 1 includes an explicit CRS property:

```
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } }
```

File 2 does not include an explicit CRS property, which I believe means CRS84 is implied ([RFC-7946](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946)).

Both files are opened by OGR's GeoJSON driver, loaded into a layer, and have their SRS inspected in the following manner.

```
driver = GetDriverByName("GeoJSON")
datasource = driver.Open("...geojson")
layer = datasource.GetLayerByIndex(0)
print(layer.GetSpatialRef().ExportToWkt())
```

Both files report the following WKT (it ends with `AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]`)

```
'GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AXIS["Latitude",NORTH],AXIS["Longitude",EAST],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]'
```

However, if I explicitly create a CRS84 SRS via OGR (using exactly the same text as File 1's CRS property), it reports a different WKT.

```
crs84_srs: Final = SpatialReference()
crs84_srs.SetFromUserInput("urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84")
print(crs84_srs.ExportToWkt())
```

This reports the following (does not end with EPSG reference)

```
'GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AXIS["Longitude",EAST],AXIS["Latitude",NORTH]]'
```

**Question**: Why does OGR treat GeoJSON as EPSG:4326 instead of CRS84, and is there anything I can do to force it to respect the explicit or implicit presence of CRS84 in the input file? I have reviewed the [driver options](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/geojson.html) but I see no likely candidates. The difference between EPSG:4326 and CRS84 is subtle but important - for example is affects axis ordering when calling `layer.GetExtent()`.

Answer (score 1):

CRS84 is the same as EPSG:4326 but with reversed axis order, so lon-lat vs. lat-lon, respectively. But GeoJSON by definition has coordinates always in lon-lat order and therefore CRS84 = EPSG:4326. Also the default coordinate system in GeoJSON is WGS84 lot-lat coordinates. All three alternatives CRS84, EPSG:4326, and no crs at all mean the same thing.

Probably the best way to write interoperable GeoJSON it to use creation option `RFC7946=YES` https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/geojson.html. Then the result will have no crs and any software that reads GeoJSON knows what it means.

Ogrinfo reports the CRS of GeoJSON that is created according to RFC7946 this way:

```
ogrinfo crs.json -al
INFO: Open of `crs.json'
      using driver `GeoJSON' successful.

Layer name: SELECT
Geometry: Polygon
Feature Count: 1
Extent: (-34.786396, 0.417717) - (-31.168008, 2.388746)
Layer SRS WKT:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
```

So GDAL seems to know how to handle the situation. It reports that the CRS is EPSG:4326 but in the data the coordinates are in longitude-latitude order. The result is the same than having CRS84 without re-mapped axis.

I have not checked from the source code what function ogrinfo is using when it gets the result `Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1` and if the info comes from the GeoJSON driver or some other place.

Comment: Several of these statements are true, but CRS84 and EPSG:4326 cannot be considered equivalent. If GeoJSON is always in lon-lat order then OGR should never report it as EPSG:4326. If you perform two coordinate transforms - one to CRS84 and another to EPSG:4326, and then call layer.GetExtent(), the order of coordinates in the envelope is reversed and therefore this is a real problem.

Comment: Furthermore, if you load GeoJSON created with RFC7946 into OGR it will still incorrectly reports its SRS as EPSG:4326, so even if you do control data creation (and in this case I don't) this will not help

Comment: Well, that is something that is hard to do totally right. Consider a system like EPSG:2393 that is officially northing-easting. There is no EPSG  code for corresponding easting-northing order. The only possibility is to store data into GeoJSON in easting-northing order, assign crs EPSG:2393, and trust that the user of GeoJSON data knows that because it is GeoJSON the first coordinate is always longitude or easting. It is indeed complicated. You may want to write to gdal-dev mailing list and ask for assistance.

Comment: If the axis order difference between CRS84 and EPSG:4326 in GeoJSON is causing problems then perhaps this could help: `Traditional GIS-friendly axis order can be restored with     OGRSpatialReference::SetAxisMappingStrategy(OAMS_TRADITIONAL_GIS_ORDER);`  https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/gdal/MIGRATION_GUIDE.TXT

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of the "traditional" axis ordering option. I will try it when I'm back at work Monday. I feel your example of EPSG:2393 doesn't really change the discussion - the reason this is causing problems is precisely because there *is* an alternate code for EPSG:4326 with the axes reversed, it's just that it's not being used where I believe I should. If I get time I will write up an example for gdal-dev and see if I get any traction

Comment: Please explain also what is the concrete problem that you have. Is that the axis order in extent?

Comment: I'm having trouble reproducing the original issue I encountered. I'm going to close the question and revisit if I am able to experience it again